# How do I read a pdf file in my iCloud Drive Desktop folder from within an iOS Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I have a simple iOS app running on an iPhone 12 Pro simulator with the task of reading a pdf file saved in my Desktop folder on my iCloud Drive. I can see the file on my macBook Pro and on my iPhone 12 Pro (real and simulator devices). But when I run the app on the simulator I cannot fetch the contents of the pdf file into the app.

Here is my Swift code in View Controller.swift;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        guard let fileURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Desktop").appendingPathComponent("samplePIL1436").appendingPathExtension("pdf") else { print("Got here 1."); return }
        
        print(fileURL)
        
        guard let pdfFileData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) else { print("Got here 2.");return }
        
        print(pdfFileData[0])
        
    }


}
```

I have added iCloud capabilities in the Signing & Capabilities tab of Xcode. And I have done all the necessary steps in my Apple Developer account regarding app ID, provisioning profile, certificate, etc.

I have also added the necessary dictionaries to the `info.plist` file.

Comment: Are you signed into your account (Phone, iCloud, App Store, etc) on your Simulator?

Comment: Yes I am signed in on both the simulator and the device.

Comment: I can see the file in iCloud Drive on the simulator using the Files app.

Comment: After a little research and testing, I don't believe your app is **allowed** to access iCloud folder outside its container in that way. You can access all files from your app via `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but not directly. That makes sense... as I wouldn't want to install an app that could - without my interaction - end up deleting every file on my iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I used `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to pick a pdf file and load it into my app.